# Extract the elements from array and put back them to another array.?

Tags: swift

suppose i have a array that have 10 elements. say,

```
var ArrayElemts : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
```

Now how can i keep the elements from 0 t0 5 in one array set and 6 to 10 to another array set?

Comment: You have 11 elements in your array sample

Answer (score 2):

Use `[0...5]` to create an `ArraySlice` and then `Array` to convert that back to an array:

```
var arrayElemts = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]

let first = Array(arrayElemts[0...5])
let second = Array(arrayElemts[6...10])

print(first)   // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
print(second)  // ["7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
```

Comment: No need to say that an array.count check is needed to avoid crashing with an array with less than 11 elements

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is the following:

```
let partition1 = array.filter { Int($0) ?? 0 <= 5 }
let partition2 = array.filter { Int($0) ?? 0 > 5 }
```

Conversion to numbers should be the first step though. You should never work with strings as if they were numbers.

```
let numbers = array.flatMap { Int($0) }

let partition1 = numbers.filter { $0 <= 5 }
let partition2 = numbers.filter { $0 > 5 }
```

If we suppose the array is sorted, there are easier options:

```
let sorted = numbers.sorted()
let partition1: [Int]
let partition2: [Int]

if let partition2start = sorted.index(where: { $0 > 5 }) {
    partition1 = Array(sorted.prefix(upTo: partition2start))
    partition2 = Array(sorted.suffix(from: partition2start))
} else {
    partition1 = sorted
    partition2 = []
}
```

which is what the native `partition` method can do:

```
var numbers = array.flatMap { Int($0) }
let index = numbers.partition { $0 > 5 }
let partition1 = Array(numbers.prefix(upTo: index))
let partition2 = Array(numbers.suffix(from: index))
```

Note the method changes the original array.

Answer (score 1):

#### Breaking the array up into `N`-sized chunks

The other answers show you how to "statically" partition the original array in different arrays using `ArraySlice`:s. Given your description, possibly you want to, generally, break up your original array into `N`-sized chunks (here: `n = 5`).

We could use the [`sequence(state:next)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence) to implement such a `chunk(bySize:)` method as an extension to `Collection`:

```
extension Collection {
    func chunk(bySize size: IndexDistance) -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(size > 0, "Chunk size must be a positive integer.")
        return sequence(
            state: (startIndex, index(startIndex, offsetBy: size, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex),
            next: { indices in
            guard indices.0 != self.endIndex else { return nil }
            indices.1 = self.index(indices.0, offsetBy: size, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            return (self[indices.0..<indices.1], indices.0 = indices.1).0
        }).map { $0 }
    }
}
```

Applied to your example:

```
var arrayElements = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
let partitions = arrayElements.chunk(bySize: 5)
/* [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    ["11"]] */
```

The `chunk(bySize:)` method will break up the array into `bySize`-sized chunks, as well as (possible) a smaller chunk for the final partition.

---

However, as much as I'd like to try to use the `sequence(state:next)` function (not needing to use any mutable intermediate variables other than `state`), the implementation above is quite bloated and difficult to read, so (as for so many other cases ...) we are probably better off simply using a `while` loop:

```
extension Collection {
    func chunk(bySize size: IndexDistance) -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(size > 0, "Chunk size must be a positive integer.")
        var chunks: [SubSequence] = []
        var from = startIndex
        while let to = index(from, offsetBy: size, limitedBy: endIndex) {
            chunks.append(self[from..<to])
            from = to
        }
        if from != endIndex { chunks.append(self[from..<endIndex]) }
        return chunks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lol I don't see why there are so complicated answers here
(Consider the "array" variable as is -> [Int], not [Any])
So the first approach is just for Number types.
The second one should do it

Simply:

```
let array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
//For instance..
var arrayA = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]

//First 6 elements
let arrayOfFirstFour = array.filter({
    return $0 <= 5 ? true : false
})

//Remaining  elements:
let restOfArray = array.filter({
    return $0 > 5 ? true : false
})

let elementsToFourth = arrayA.prefix(upTo: 4)
let elementsAfterFourth = arrayA.suffix(from: 4)
print(arrayOfFirstFour)
print(restOfArray)
print(elementsToFourth)
print(elementsAfterFourth)

//[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
//[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
//["A", "B", "C", "D"]
//["E", "F", "G"]
```

Comment: Talking about unnecessary complications `let arrayOfFirstFour = array.filter{ $0 <= 5 }`

Comment: If the intent is to get the first n elements just use array.prefix(n)

Comment: What if the array is `["x", "a", "1", "4", "foo", "11", "3"]`? I believe the _values_ of the elements in the the array of the question are simply examples, whereas the question covers splitting the elements based on their _positions_ (not _values_!), so your value-based filters are somewhat misleading. The `prefix` and `suffix` approaches are good though (as has already been covered in [@Sulthan:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228455/4573247)), given that the array is to be split into exactly two arrays (without actually removing the "split" element).

Comment: @LeoDabus : Maybe I am a bit sceptical, but the ternary operator seems a bit like (I know what I am doing) :D

Comment: Note that prefix(n) is different from prefix(upTo: n)